# Build Apple Silicon Apps on Macbook Pro 2015

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, xcode, apple-silicon

I have an old Macbook Pro 2015 (15" 16GB 512GB) and want to build macOS native desktop apps that also run on apple silicon.

Since I cannot run the latest macOS version and thus also Xcode version, I'm not sure how to measure the drawbacks of doing this.
I think Monterey is the latest version i can run.

Is it possible to build Apple Silicon Apps on MacBook Pro 2015?

Comment: I've edited this to contain the most on-topic of the three ones you posed. Hit us up on [meta] please for advice on asking the two others. Shopping and worth are very dependent on your business model and value of your time. We can objectively answer the first, however. Those answers will hopefully assist in asking the follow on questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is you can and should get started with what you have. The i7 versions were beasts and even if you had the lesser powered 13 inch model, it's very capable for compiling and debugging. Only by running into the road blocks that affect you and your project will you be able to measure the value of newer hardware. (And you're going to do a far better job knowing how you develop and your needs than out assumptions will).

- Xcode 15 requires Ventura and the [last version that you can likely run is Xcode 14.2](https://xcodereleases.com) which is about a year old now.

Apple doesn't support macOS Ventura on that era hardware, but you should investigate Open Core Legacy Patcher to see if Ventura or Sonoma is workable on your specific Mac. Do this when you find something that makes you think you'll benefit greatly from running the latest Xcode instead of the version that's compatible with the OS that Apple thinks that hardware should run (which is macOS 12 Monterey) or when you're stuck and not developing so you can plan for the future.

Specifically, yes you can compile Apple Silicon apps from Xcode on macOS Monterey from Intel as that's all anyone had to compile for the M1 before it came out. Very good work was done, compiling, debugging, supporting with that hardware so you might be able to postpone a purchase until after your app is in the store or you're ready to invest in newer, faster hardware.

When it's time to invest, don't overlook an entry level M1 mini (used or the new $599 M2 mini) sitting at work, home or school and screen sharing from your portable to develop. They are incredibly cost-effective and powerful. As long as Apple is still supporting and patching your OS (or you OCLP and the side effects are minimal) you can save on a new portable "does everything you need" Mac and free up your first Apple Silicon Mac for just pure dev tasks.

Comment: thank you so much. this makes sense. will give it a try and decide on the get go.

Comment: For sure @uloco You should be able to run some Apple demo code projects and make sure you can use Cloud build in short order and come up with a game plan. I went with the absolute cheapest M1 mini on release day and now have a M2 Air 512 storage and am delighted at how well the entry level models blow away my Intel hardware, but the Intel still can do lots of work for you. I wouldn't make extra RAM a must have - 512 storage is must have if you have personal data on the Mac in addition to Xcode and projects. 256 is very functional for development if you have nothing personal on that Mac IMO.